# Ubuntu on Windows 10. Where is my USB mounted?

Tags: usb, mount, windows-10

I am new to Windows and installed the Ubuntu image from the Windows store so that I would have a more familiar environment to fall back upon.  Not so.  I am still finding my way around the filesystem but still cannot find my portable USB. `lsusb` produces nothing and `lsblk` produces the following error:

```
 lsblk: failed to access sysfs directory: /sys/dev/block: No such file or directory
```

Comment: This is not a real Ubuntu. It is ubuntu shell. You can't interact with hardware from there. It should be something like "Disk F:" in Windows.

Comment: Just what I was gonna say...You can't access your GPU either...The exciting part is updates are "in the works"!

Comment: Are you talking about WSL2? If so, it doesn't have external device support yet but it is high priority at Microsoft so it will be available soon...

Comment: two years later, win11 and still no external device support?

Comment: Eh my bad.. a proper search shows, win11 is supposed to have external device support for WSL2 on win11 (and 10). but installation under ubuntu fails here with me.